# Vanishing tikz pictures in arxiv compilation

Tags: tikz-pgf, arxiv

I have a paper which compiles fine on my system [pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)], and which compiled fine on the arxiv as of May 2016, but ... when I try to update the arxiv version now, some of the tikz pictures vanish.

Notes:

- the tex of these tikz pictures is completely unchanged from the version which compiled fine on the arxiv last year
- there are no warnings or error messages in the arxiv compilation, but those tikz pictures are simply gone from the pdf (space for them remains)
- I know the arxiv is still using an old version of tex (perhaps 2011) but that wouldn't seem to explain the change in behavior since last year
- I realize that in theory I can compile each tikz picture separately and switch to includegraphics, but I'd like to avoid resorting to that if possible

Question: has anyone encountered anything like this, or have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You could make a new document with only one of the problematic TikZ pictures and test. -and proceed to comment lines to identify the exact problem.

Comment: Does the log file have any useful information (maybe an error or some warning message)

Comment: The arxiv has just been updated to a variant of TeX Live 2016, otherwise, try running a diff of the two tex files and checking there were no other files included in the previous upload which you are missing.  Have you explicitly checked through the log file for errors/warnings?

Comment: Just for the record, it seems this is due to subtle differences in the version of tikz-pgf used by the arxiv and by my version of TeXLive.  I don't know what those differences are, but eventually I managed to massage the tikz code (without changing the actual output) so that it would compile on the arxiv version of tikz.

Comment: @Chris Can you tell me roughly what you did? (I have the same problem.)